# Django NameError

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, error-handling

I setup python and django and was just trying to build a simple app 'mysite'

I created the views.py in root folder, while my urls.py is in root/mysite/
When i call the /hello it gives me the following error. What should i do to fix it?

```
NameError at /hello
name 'hello' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    ~~:8000/hello
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'hello' is not defined
Exception Location: c:\Python27\Django-1.5\mysite\mysite\urls.py in <module>, line 17
Python Executable:  c:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['c:\\Python27\\Django-1.5\\mysite',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pymysql-0.3-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'c:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'c:\\Python27',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 26 Mar 2013 18:40:41 +0530
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                    response = middleware_method(request)
 ...
▶ Local vars
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py in process_request
            if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
 ...
▶ Local vars
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in is_valid_path
        resolve(path, urlconf)
 ...
▶ Local vars
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
 ...
▶ Local vars
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in resolve
            for pattern in self.url_patterns:
 ...
▶ Local vars
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in url_patterns
        patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
 ...
▶ Local vars
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in urlconf_module
            self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
 ...
▶ Local vars
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py in import_module
    __import__(name)
 ...
▶ Local vars
c:\Python27\Django-1.5\mysite\mysite\urls.py in <module>
                       ('^hello/$', hello),
 ...
```

Comment: What is in your urls.py?  Is there a route for /hello?

Answer (score 3):

Change below line in urls.py

```
('^hello/$', hello),
```

to

```
('^hello/$', 'views.hello'),
```

or if you are using prefix then do

```
('^hello/$', 'hello'),
```

or do

```
from views import hello
```

Comment: He's missing the final '/' in the request or a route that's missing the '^hello$'

Answer (score 0):

```
c:\Python27\Django-1.5\mysite\mysite\urls.py in <module>
                       ('^hello/$', hello),
```

You have not defined `hello`,  I believe you can either import hte function or reference it as a string

```
from mysite.myapp.views import hello
```

or

```
'mysite.myapp.views.hello'
```